# SSIS lookup transform

Tags: ssis, transform, lookup, bids

In SSIS I have a lookup transform which performs the function of only inserting new data into the table, call it tableY. So the process is the following:

```
0) Aggregate (group by) the primary key for the input row
1) Do a lookup with the current input row on tableY using the primary key
2) Insert the input row if there is not a match (the current row does not exist in tableY)
```

I get the error that I have "violated the integrity constraints of the primary key column"

How is this possible since all inputs are unique and the output of the transform is "lookup no match output"?

Comment: Do u have composite primary keys  ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your lookup transform is using a cached copy of TableY. Try selecting "no cache" on the Lookup Transformation Editor (the load time may suffer though).

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes.aspx) for more information on lookup cache modes.